# Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:compailer:1.1.1 error

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create a room database in the android studio. but when I build project, I am taking "Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:compailer:1.1.1" this error.

my gradle version is 3.4.1
android studio version is 3.4.1
I am using java as a programming language.
 can somebody help me

I searched this error on the net but could not find anything.

'''
    my gradle file:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.archroomdatabase"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
 optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

dependencies {
def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
def room_version = "1.1.1"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//lifecycle components
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compailer:$lifecycle_version"

//Room components
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"}
```

my gradle project file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**this is the error :**

**Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:compailer:1.1.1**

Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/compailer/1.1.1/compailer-1.1.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/compailer/1.1.1/compailer-1.1.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/compailer/1.1.1/compailer-1.1.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/compailer/1.1.1/compailer-1.1.1.jar

Required by:
    project :app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelt it wrong, it's not

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compailer:$lifecycle_version"
```

it's

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```